# A toggle between 2 elements in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> I am writing a toggle in pure JavaScript.

There are 2 input fields, 1 is hidden and the other is visible. When we click on the first 1, the second input should appear and when both of the input fields are visible and one of the input fields is clicked then that input field should display:block and the other input field should display:none. Also, the latest clicked input element should remain on top and the other one below it. (es6 would be also good)

---

if anyone knows please check ?

### code

```
<form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww" placeholder="Type "></form>
<form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww1" placeholder="Type "></form>
```

---

```
body{
  background:#873e66;
}
.input-bg{
  background:white;
  border:none;
  color:black;
  height:50px;
  text-indent:15px;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:26px;
  outline:none;
}
.neww1{
  margin-top:5px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}
.neww1{
  display:none;
}
```

---

```
function toggleClass(element, className){
    if (!element || !className){
        return;
    }

    var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
    if (nameIndex == -1) {
        classString += ' ' + className;
    }
    else {
        classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
    }
    element.className = classString;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Are you having issues, and if so what are they? How is this related to React?

Comment: @Jayce444 I want to add this toggle bar in side a react component that's why I selected react. I am sorry if its not related ill remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your requirement is not very clear but my answer might be of some help

Let's say we have two input fields like this:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Input 1" class="myInput first" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Input 2" class="myInput second hidden" />
</div>
```

CSS can be like:

```
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myInput {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px
}
.first {
  order: 1;
}
.second {
  order: 2;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Now the toggle function (JS):

```
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.myInput');
allInputs.forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var allHiddenInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
      if(allHiddenInputs.length === 0) {
        allInputs.forEach(function(input) {
          input.classList.add("hidden");
          input.classList.add("second");
          input.classList.remove("first");
        });
        node.classList.remove("hidden");
        node.classList.remove("second");
        node.classList.add("first");
      } else {
        allHiddenInputs.forEach(function(input) {
          input.classList.remove("hidden");
        });
      }
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/rrqvQz?editors=1010

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i tried in codepen this is not working can you please check again, thanks

Comment: Check the codepen link I've mentioned in my answer and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: yes thank you, one more thing is it possible to make a small modification     
 =>  when input 2 is selected it should be at first and when 1 is selected it should be on first , now input 1 is always on first  by deault

Comment: check the codepen link again and let me know if this is what you want

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Can you please mark this answer as accepted. Moreover, you can drop me an email at vickyddev@gmail.com if you have any concerns, I won't be able to reply immediately as I'm at work but I certainly will.

Comment: i texted you and also, I tried to add your answer also as right one, but  i am unable to add your answer as right one its saying I don't have enough points to do it  :(

Comment: Its not about answer being right or wrong but the one that suits the needs of OP. No issues though. You can simply check/uncheck or click an up-vote :)

Answer (score 2):

you can proceed like :

```js
const inputs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("input-bg"));
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  console.log()
  input.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const somehidden = inputs.filter((_input) => {
      return _input.getAttribute("class").match(/neww1/i);
    })
    if (somehidden.length > 0) {
      somehidden[0].classList.remove("neww1");
    } else {
      inputs.forEach((i) => {
        if (i !== event.target)
          i.classList.add("neww1");
      });

    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #873e66;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "up" "down";
}

form:focus-within {
  grid-area: up;
}

.input-bg {
  background: white;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  height: 50px;
  text-indent: 15px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  outline: none;
}

.neww1 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.neww1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww" placeholder="Type "></form>
  <form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww1" placeholder="Type2 "></form>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to keep the current selected input field always on top when toggling ?

Comment: yes, you can do it using display grid css3 , i have modified the response

Comment: i got this from another answer , I was expecting like this https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/rrqvQz?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You have the classList attribute with your HTML Element.
So first you need the element reference, you can use your constructor and private variables and set the private variable with document.getElementByClassName according to initial state of your page, or set an ID. Let's take for example an ID :

```
<form onclick="toggleClass()" id="password1" action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww" placeholder="Type "></form>

<form onclick="toggleClass()" id="password2" action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off"><input name="p" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww1" placeholder="Type "></form>
```

Then just find the reference

```
const password1 = document.getElementById("password1");
const password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
```

and after that, you can write this function :

```
function toggleClass() {
  const password1 = document.getElementById("password1");
  const password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
  if (password1.classList.contains('hidden')){
    password1.classList.remove('hidden');
    password2.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  else {
    password2.classList.remove('hidden');
    password1.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

.neww1 {
  background-color : red;
}
.neww {
  background-color : green;
}
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
input {
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried in codepen its not working and showing 1 bracket missing. I added it then also its not working, can you please check thank you @Shining

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot a ')' after the if. And the reason because  it do not work it about the copy past. It's okay now. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLMqYp

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help you. I'm directly changing the CSS but you can also toggle classes using the `classList`.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off">
        <input name="p" id="input1" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww"
            placeholder="Input One ">
    </form>

    <form action="#" class="navbar-top" role="search" autocomplete="off">
        <input name="p" id="input2" data-hit="Type" type="text" autocomplete="new-password" value="" data-open="false" class="input-bg neww1"
            placeholder="Input Two ">
    </form>


    <script>
        (function () {
            const inputOne = document.getElementById('input1');
            const inputTwo = document.getElementById('input2');

            const handleClick = i => (i === inputOne ? inputTwo : inputOne)
                .style.display = 'none';

            const handleBlur = i => {
                if (i === inputOne) {
                    inputTwo.style.display = 'block';
                    inputOne.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    inputTwo.style.display = 'none';
                    inputOne.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }

            [inputOne, inputTwo].forEach((i) => {
                i.addEventListener('click', () => handleClick(i))
                i.addEventListener('focusout', () => handleBlur(i))
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am was expecting something when we click the input A, input B should come under it and then when we click A or B other input should hide